# DRF - Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am testing django rest framework using python requests module but its says an error. I am just beginner rest-api developer.

DRF setting main.py

```
import datetime

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    )
}


JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',  # Authorization: JWT <token>
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
}
```

and my testing code is

```
import os
import json
import requests

AUTH_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/jwt/'
ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/status/'

image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'drf.png')


headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = {
    "username": 'jaki',
    "password": 'SADHIN101119'
}

r = requests.post(AUTH_ENDPOINT, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
token = r.json()['token']

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "JWT" + token
}


post_data = json.dumps({"content": "some random content"})
posted_response = requests.post(ENDPOINT, data=post_data, headers=headers)
print(posted_response.text)
```

Error showing

> {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

How can i solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You missed a space in "JWT" , it must be "JWT "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Authorization` header, the `JWT` prefix and token must be separated with a space. Change your `Authorization` header to:

```
"Authorization": "JWT " + token
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This a a hunch ... but uncomment out

```
# 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
```

When you're trying to get your Token, you're using BasicAuth to send over your login creds. That's probably failing.